# Creating variables in loop for dynamicly creating griddata()

Tags: python, arrays, grid

I am trying to write a function for a numerical algorithm.  The funciton should take in number of dimensions and upper and lower bounds for some state variables.  Then, I would like the function to create a state space over the dimensions.  I can easily write this using griddata and statically defining the number of dimensions, but I would like to define the space dynamically.  Can someone tell me how to create arrays dynamically to pass to meshgrid?  Or explain how to unpack a dictionary (as this seems to be the suggested method) into arrays?  Or even how to pass meshgrid a list of arrays?

Here is the static version of what I'm doing:

```
import numpy as np

#Define the bounds of the state space
up_bound = 1
low_bound = 0

#Define the number of dimensions
dim = 4
m = 2^j - 1, where j is the identifier of the grid.
j = 6

#Define number of points
m = 2**j - 1

#Define the state space axes using the linear space function
Xi = np.linspace(low_bound, up_bound, m)
Phi = np.linspace(low_bound, up_bound, m)
omega = np.linspace(low_bound, up_bound, m)
delta = np.linspace(low_bound, up_bound, m)

space = np.asarray(np.meshgrid(Xi, Phi, omega, delta))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`*` argument-unpacking operator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). It allows you to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to a function:

```
import numpy as np

up_bound = 1
low_bound = 0
dim = 4
j = 6
m = 2**j - 1

space = np.asarray(np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(low_bound, up_bound, m)]*dim))
```

The above code creates very large arrays as `dim` grows, and for a fairly uninteresting result -- there is a lot of repetition in the array, `space`.

You are almost surely better off -- and in the process will save space and time -- by using the `sparse=True` parameter:

```
space = np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(low_bound, up_bound, m)]*dim, sparse=True)
```

Done this way, `space` will be a list of `dim` arrays, whose shapes will broadcast to the size and shape of their un-sparsified brethren. For example, if you have some function like

```
def f(x):
    return x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + x[2] - x[3]
```

with

```
space = np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(low_bound, up_bound, m)]*dim, sparse=True)
space_old = np.asarray(np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(low_bound, up_bound, m)]*dim))
```

then computing f(space) gives the same result as f(space_old)

```
In [140]: np.allclose(f(space_old), f(space))
Out[140]: True
```

However, `space` will be significantly smaller than `space_old`, and *a lot* faster to generate:

```
In [148]: %timeit np.asarray(np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(low_bound, up_bound, m)]*dim))
1 loops, best of 3: 635 ms per loop

In [149]: %timeit np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(low_bound, up_bound, m)]*dim, sparse=True)
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.1 µs per loop
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the speedy response.  Now the real question: do you have any idea how to speed up meshgrid?  I've tried cython and it doesn't give me much more speed.